# What is the correct permission to get access to pull request checks?

Tags: github, github-api

I have a curl command that returns a 403 when I try to access this specific url:

`https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo}/commits/{sha}/check-runs`

According to the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-check-runs-for-a-git-reference I need a `checks:read` permission.

However, running the curl command I get a `403` response and this response header: `x-accepted-github-permissions: checks=read`

So, I am confident my PAT is working as I can do other calls and this response confirms my incorrect permissions.

So what additional permission do I need to grant my PAT so this command will run successfully?

Comment: Can you show your command?

Comment: ```curl -I -H "Authorization: token {token}" \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
     -H "User-Agent: {github_username}" \
     "https://api.github.com/repos/{org}/{repo}/commits/{sha}/check-runs"```

Comment: It should be `Bearer`, not `token`, no?

Comment: this commadn works eactly if I just take `check-runs` out, so that's not wrong. it's the PAT without the correct permissions.

Comment: Weirdly, I don't even see the "Checks" scope when creating a fine-grained PAT, but there is [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/authentication/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens?apiVersion=2022-11-28#repository-permissions-for-checks) implying that it should be a scope you can choose! What scopes did you pick when creating the fine-grained PAT?

Comment: I'm right there with you man, it should be there and it isn't. I haven't tried loot all on the permissions, but maybe I give that a go an binary search my way to one that works.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/36441#discussioncomment-8719793) seems relevant. "Disabled due to a couple edge cases"...

Comment: That is amazing, I was just looking at the request object and trying to guess how to modify it to add that permission in. :) Good find

Answer (score 0):

The answer as of 2024-03-28, which is confirmed via support ticket from Github, is that this cannot be done with a Peronal Access Token(PAT). We can update this answer in the future when they turn it back on.